# Access to navigationController in a customCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `collectionView` with customCells and in the first one (indexPath 0) I have a `Button`.

[image]

I'd want that when I click it, I go into another ViewController but I can't access to the `navigationController` because my cell is a `UICollectionViewCell`.

How can I get the access to the `navigationController`?

Comment: what do you mean by not acessing to the navigation controller..?

Comment: You need to have the button call a method in your class that's responsible for displaying the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: you want to go to next VC when clicking on the add button..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Button` action pragmatically in your current `ViewController`, inside `CollectionViewDataSource` method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for that cell this way.

```
cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

After that add this method in your `ViewController`

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    //perform navigation now
}
```

Comment: What if I use a custom DataSource class ? I don't have access to my NavigationController.

Comment: @Balanced Don't get your question can you please provide more details ?

Comment: What if the implementation of the CollectionViewDataSource is done in a separate class ? How can I perform the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a Delegate Protocol and Property for the Cell

One good option for this would be to create a delegate protocol and delegate property for your `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses.

The protocol makes it clear how the cell communicates its needs back to the interested party (as opposed to having a button's target/action set somewhere externally to the class) and creates an area for extending this communication in the future.

Additionally, if you ever need to add more communication with the cell's delegate, all you have to do is add a new required or optional method instead of having to wiring anything else up, the added benefit of this is a user of the cell class can look at the protocol's declaration and instantly know how the cell communicates with another object without having to know a bunch of private implementation details such as the existence of the button, etc. Wiring up a button may be the shortest path right now, but ultimately that's not very good coding practice and does not follow the concepts of Separation of Concerns.

The delegate property could be very simple for that specific cell type for example (Objective-C):

```
@protocol AddRecipeCollectionViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)cellDidRequestAddRecipeAction:(AddRecipeCollectionViewCell *)cell;

@end

@interface AddRecipeCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<AddRecipeCollectionViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

*(Note: Swift code needed here, I'll update answer with the Swift equivalent, but I need to research the syntax since I don't use it every day, anyone else feel free to contribute the Swift equivalent to this answer if you get to it first)*